# calling a public method from a different class private method

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a method in Class A (see below) and i would like to run that method based on a selection change of a drop down in Class B. I am not sure how it call that method can someone help me/point me in the right direction.

```
public void CloseloadHistory()
    {
        if (canHistory.Height != 0.0)
        {

            canHistory.Height = 0;
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/DrScribe.EMR;component/Images/Collapse.png");
            image.EndInit();

            imgHistory.Source = image;
        }
        else loadHistory();
    }
```

Comment: Simply create an instance of classA and then you call the public methods. It is basic 101 object oriented programming.

Comment: Or make this method static and use A.closeloadHistory();

Comment: Yes but given the question I suggest to stop here and go back to a good introductory text on OOP.

Comment: Just as a general tip, in WPF it's not a good practice to change UI stuff (like `Height` in your code) in the `ViewModel` or code behind (only in rare cases where this is a must).
It's recommended that you set the `Visibility="Collapsed"` on the `canHistory` UI element by using a converter or something similar. (I guess that you should read some more about this topic)

Comment: thanks for the tip, i just started working with WPF and in the exsiting code they are Collapsing it by setting the height to 0, so i did not want to change the flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void ClassBMethod()
{
    ClassA classA = new ClassA();
    classA.CloaseLoadHistory();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to instantiate the class of the method (let us say its ClassA) and just call the Method.

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
a.CloseloadHistory();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to instantiate the object containing your method, you can make your method static but only if you're able to make the canHistory variable static as well.

Then you'll be able to call your method like this

```
ClassA.StaticCloseloadHistory();
```